# BIDS 2008 expand fonts available

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, fonts

I added new fonts in Windows. When preparing a new report in Business Intelligence Development Studio, the new fonts are not available in combobox for FontFamily in Properties of a report element.

I can use some of the new fonts in report by building an expression `="New Font"`. The fonts available in combobox are presented as "Constants" in Expression Builder. Is there some way to expand the list of constants for FontFamily and therefore to make new fonts easily accessed for usage?